# How to automate file Upload content recorded in json format in body

Tags: loadrunner

I have to check the performance of Excel File upload in my application. The application is developed in .Net.

When the file is uploaded it is being converted into json format at UI level and then the data is getting uploaded into the application.

So when the scenario is recorded the content in the Excel file is showing in body. The file name is not showing anywhere in the log as the content is converted into Json format at UI level.  I have tried by adding  multipart/form data and file path but no success.  I also tried the  captured the requests using Fiddler but the same requests are recorded.

When discussed with dev team they said they have written a code in angular js /java script and converting the data in the file into json format and then saving it into the application.

There is no sign of uploaded file name in the log.

Can anyone advice me how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing an HTTP level script. There is no "filename" or anything like that at that level. You just need to simulate sending the data from the client to the server. There are two options (as far as I can see)

1) The application loads the user file to the browser, parses it, sends JSON to the server.

In this case you only need to **send the JSON to the server** in your script. All the rest is done in the client which is irrelevant to your load test.

2) The file is uploaded to the server, then the server updates the client, then the client sends the JSON data back to the server.

I very much doubt this is the case, but if it is then you will need to simulate the upload of the file AND the sending of the parsed data. Please read about file uploading in LoadRunner in the ample online literature about that.